# C# Unable to parse negative value double

Tags: c#, linq

I'm using LINQ to read in some XML and then use that to set properties in an object. The XML looks like this:

```
<display_location>
<full>London, United Kingdom</full>
<city>London</city>
<state/>
<state_name>United Kingdom</state_name>
<country>UK</country>
<country_iso3166>GB</country_iso3166>
<zip>00000</zip>
<magic>553</magic>
<wmo>03772</wmo>
<latitude>51.47999954</latitude>
<longitude>-0.44999999</longitude>
<elevation>24.00000000</elevation>
</display_location>
```

And the code I have is:

```
select new Forecast
{
    //Set properties for the display location
    DisplayLatitude = (double)i.Element("display_location").Element("latitude"),
    DisplayLongtitude = (double)i.Element("display_location").Element("longtitude"),
    DisplayElevation = (string)i.Element("display_location").Element("elevation"),
};
```

I can correctly set the latitude and elevation however I'm getting the exception "Value cannot be null" when I try to parse the longtitude.

I think it might be because of the negative symbol. How do I fix this?

Comment: Spelling. Its not `.Element("longtitude")`, it should be `.Element("longitude")`

Answer (score 3):

It's "longitude", not "longtitude". Your string needs to exactly match the XML element name or you'll get a null value instead.